# STM32: I2C Master Slave code does not work

Tags: stm32, i2c, interrupts, nucleo, hal

I have two board: nucleo U575zi-q & nucleo L432kc

u575 is the master board, l432 is slave. I want to transfer data between Them, and below is my two codes.
this is my master's code

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Falling_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    printf("Success at Master EXTI Callback\n");
  if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_13){
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, addr<<1, TX_Buffer, 1);
  }
}

void HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    printf("Success at Master Transmit\n");
    while(HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, addr<<1, 10, 10)!=HAL_OK){
    }
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, addr<<1, RX_Buffer, 1);
}

void HAL_I2C_MasterRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    printf("Success at Master Receive\n");
    printf("%d\n",RX_Buffer[0]);
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

And this is Slave code

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

/* Prepare for Receiving Data */   
HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, RX_Buffer, 1);

/* USER CODE END 2 */ ............................................

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    printf("Success at Slave Receive\n");
    if(RX_Buffer[0]=='H'){
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_12);
    }
    HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, TX_Buffer, 1);
}

void HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    printf("Success at Slave Transmit\n");
    HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, RX_Buffer, 1);
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

Which I want is:

1. When I click user button, EXTI IT works and it send data to slave
2. slave receives data and toggle led, and transmit it's data to master.(slave transmit will be started by master)
3. master receives data and finish
4. when I re-click the button, 1-3 repeats again

BUT, It works for a one loop(1-3) and it does not work for one more time. when I re-click the button, it does not work..

During Debugging, I know that master receive or slave transmit is go wrong, but I'm confused because my first trial was success. it does not work for 2nd trial and 3.4.5...

PLEASE HELP ME THIS IS CONNECTED TO MY SCHOOL RESEARCH!!!!

I CAN USE OSCILOSCOPE SO PLEASE HELP ME